# Calculating insurance in Risk Management

Tags: probability

I have a scenario....

A House is worth $200,000
chance of burning down accidentally each year p = 0.001 (1/100000)
threat of flooding accidentally each year p = 0.0001 (1/1000000)

Question is "What should we pay to insure the house, if either a flood or fire will destroy the house completely?"

My calcuation is:

considering if we want to be able to buy a house with same value,
$200,000* 0.999 (no-accident) + $200,000*0.001 (burning accident) - insurance
= $200,000 - insurance

Insurance value should be $200 or less. ($200 = $200,000*0.001)

Appreciate if someone can advise if this make sense. Thanks.

Comment: Where did you take the possibility of a flood into account?

Comment: When you write $p=0.001$, is that a simple number ($1/1000$) or is it actually a percentage, $0.001$% ($1/100,000$)? If it is a percentage it is incorrect to simply multiply $200,000*0.001$ and write the result in dollars; you should also divide by $100$. (On the other hand, you should insure against the expected losses for both fire _and_ flood, not just fire).

Comment: To get dollar signs, you need to escape them by preceding them with a backslash.  Otherwise the site takes it as math and makes the italics you see.

Comment: Not quite.  See my answer.

Comment: Let me know if that helped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If either a fire or flood occurs, the value of the house is zero.  Thus, the expected value $EV$ of the house is given by
$$EV=200,000(1-p_{flood})(1-p_{fire})+0p_{flood}(1-p_{fire})+0p_{fire}(1-p_{}flood)+0p_{flood}p_{fire}$$
$$=200,000(1-p_{flood})(1-p_{fire})$$
$$=200,000(1-0.001)(1-0.0001)$$
which is $199,780.02$.

Now, $EV$ must be equal to the replacement cost $RC$ of the house minus the cost to insure $CI$ the house.

Thus, $EV=RC-IC$, which implies the $IC=RC-EV=200,000=199,780.02=219.98$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But I don't quite understand this part "0p flood (1−p fire )+0p fire (1−p flood)+0p flood p fire " in calculating EV.

Comment: Sure. Those terms are joint probabilities. So, if there is a flood (probability of a flood is $p_{flood}$) and no fire (probability of no fire is $1-p_{fire}$) (note that the joint probability of a flood and no fire is $p_{flood}(1-p_{fire})$), then the house is worth $0$.  Similarly, if there is a fire (probability is $p_{fire}$), an no flood (probability of no flood is $1-p_{flood}$), then the house is worth $0$.  Finally, if there is no fire and no flood, then the house is worth $0$.